# SKlearn stating there is a nan in data set when it isn't present

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have been using a simple random forest tree model and just added some columns to the data I am working with but now I am getting this error:

```
Input X contains NaN.
RandomForestClassifier does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively.
For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively.
Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values.
```

There are no missing values in my data so I am a bit stuck I will add my code so that if there is a problem with selecting the features it will be clear.

```
col_names = ["MaxCorticalThickness","MinCorticalThickness","Random thickness 1","Random thickness 2","Random thickness 3","MaxThicknessAngle","MinThicknessAngle","SizeClass"]


feature_cols = ["MaxCorticalThickness","MinCorticalThickness","Random thickness 1","Random thickness 2","Random thickness 3","MaxThicknessAngle","MinThicknessAngle"]

X = data[feature_cols] # Features
y = data.SizeClass # Target variable

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

# Create Decision Tree classifer object
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100) 

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I still think there are `nan` values in your data. What is the output of `data.isna().sum().sum()`? Also `RandomForestClassifier` only accepts numerical data, so that might be an issue here. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Check column data type: print(data[feature_cols].dtypes)
Perhaps there is string data, it must be numeric.